# Menu Softkey is not displaying on Android Lollipop Devices [Nexus 9 and nexus 5]

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-optionsmenu, nexus-5

I cant seem to find the `Menu softkey` on my Nexus 9 and nexus 5 [Android Version Lollipop]. All the apps that i had developed which contained `option menu` are not displaying `menu softkey`. So i am unable to access that `option menu`.

Also some of my apps don't use `Actionbar/Toolbar` because of their design requirements so i am looking for a solution without adding `Actionbar/Toolbar`.

So i was wondering, Is there a way to display `Menu softKey in Android Lollipop` ?

**Updated:**

[image]
This is a sample app that i found on my Nexus 9. As you can see it has the `action overflow button` for legacy apps. Can anyone tell me how the did that ?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

> If your app runs on a device without a dedicated Menu button, the
>   system decides whether to add the action overflow to the navigation
>   bar based on which API levels you declare to support in the 
>   manifest element. The logic boils down to:
>
> **If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
>   the system will not add the legacy overflow button.**
>
> Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running
>   on Android 3.0 or higher.
>
> The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower,
>   set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
>   the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
>   on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

So basically check your Manifest file.

Comment: May be its a hack but for showing option menu on lollipop is changed my build target to lollipop 5.0.1 and added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" /> to manifest file.
And now it shows the action overflow icon. Though i am still confuse that setting only minsdkversion in manifest worked

Answer (score 2):

Add

- YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity
- Add method onCreateOptionsMenu  and inflate menu  (getMenuInflater().inflate()(R.menu.menu_file, menu);
- Add to res->menu-> menu_test.xml  ->   any item with(app:showAsAction="ifRoom")